# How to test a struts 2.1.x developer?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, struts2

We employ a test to filter out candidates who should not be applying for a position. The tests are designed to be very low effort for those who should be applying and too much effort for those who are not experienced.

Here is an example of a test we give to a candidate applying for a job of “java web application developer on an Oracle project”:

```
We only work with contractors who can use the tools we use, to determine if you can use the tools we have devised some very simple tests.

Instructions

If you are prepared and knowledgeable this will take you about 2-5 minutes.

Suggested knowledge and tools:

* subversion 1.6 see http://subversion.tigris.org/ or http://cygwin.com/setup.exe
* java 1.6 see http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp
* oracle >=10g see http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/jdev/index.html
* j2ee server see http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi or http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/

Steps
1. check out svn://statics32.pdinc.us/home/subversion/guest
2. deploy the war file found at trunk/test.war
3. browse to the web application you installed from the war file and answer the one SQL question: How many rows are in the table 'testdata' where column 'value' ends with either an 'A' or an 'a'? The login credentials are in trunk/doc/oracle.txt
4. make a RESULTS HASH by submitting your answer to the form.
5. create a file in tmp/YourUserName.txt and put the RESULTS HASH in it, not the answer.
6. check in your file (don't forget to add the file first).
7. message me with the revision number of your check in.
```

As such I am looking for ideas on how to test for someone to be a struts 2.1 w/ annotations.

Comment: That's an excellent way to get mediocre employees. No one truly good will jump through those hoops.

Comment: And what would you do when you have to select consultants which you cannot interview face to face?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/02/the-nonprogramming-programmer.html might explain the motives a little better than I can.

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

> If you are prepared and knowledgeable
>   this will take you about 2-5 minutes.

makes real pressure. Setting up a develop environment needs:  user logins, password,jdbc-urls and should be basic coaching for a job. In my opinion it's highly unfair. I think since I faced no problems with cvs or subversion I could do this with any VCS. Having experience with lot's of databases I should have the time to google how this URL looks like. And **btw tomcat isn't a j2ee** server.
You should rather find out whether the applicants are motivated and get them in line.
If you don't have the time to explain project structure or do coaching (since you can't provide any documentation) you probably have a different problem.

Comment: Valid points of view here, I should have been more clear. On the job the employee will have all the support to make their job smooth. The concept of the pressure is to filter those who would be pressured by this. When we post a job we get hundreds of responses, most of them should not be applying. As to the "having time" the test is not timed, it is done off site at the candidate's choosing. The "If you are prepared and knowledgeable this will take you about 2-5 minutes" is referring to a user who already has subversion, jboss/tomcat/oc4j/... installed on their system.

Comment: Hope I wasn't offending. What about asking the applicants about solutions to issues you actually have in your projects, this could be good way too find more about their skills.

Comment: No ofense, you helped understand the perception issues at hand.

We do that during the technical interview. This is really just a "resume filter" we get way to much spam.